# Chrome address bar Google search engine

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, search-engine

I am using google chrome as a browser and fire up empty tags and type directly to the address the search query. The problem that raises is despite the fact that I had defined google.com as a default search engine for my browser, still it gets regionalized and I get results from google.dk. Any suggestions on how to set the address bar seach engine of chrome to google.com when I am outside of US?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, follow these steps:

- Click the wrench on the toolbar
- Select Options (or Preferences or Settings depending on your OS)
- Go in the Basics tab
- Click `Manage Seach Engines` in the Search section
- Go to the bottom of the page and add the correct settings for Google.com, ie http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=%s for the URL part.
- Now select it and select Make default

This should do the trick.